# Android SSL Certificate Authentication (with the Android KeyChain API) to a WCF Service

Tags: android, wcf, ssl, keychain

I have big problems with getting the certificates running under android.
I have an android client which connects to a WCF-Service.

I think the problem is, that the certificates are not transfered. I get an error message: 
403 forbidden (in the response). I really hope you can help me. 
=> in my android client

In internet explorer, it works just fine => status 200

I found this article: 
http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/03/unifying-key-store-access-in-ics.html

"A common use of the private key is for SSL client authentication. This can be implemented by using an HttpsURLConnection with a custom X509KeyManager that returns the PrivateKey retrieved from the KeyChain API. The open source Email application for ICS uses KeyChain with an X509ExtendedKeyManager. To learn more, have a look at the source code (in SSLUtils.java)."

I have checked out the SSLUtils class and I am trying to use it.

Here is some code:

```
private void setHttpsAdvanced() {
    HostAuth ht = new HostAuth();
    ht.mPort = 443;
    ht.mClientCertAlias = "jensZert";

    HttpParams params = getHttpParams();
    MyThreadSafeClientConnManager ccm = MyThreadSafeClientConnManager
            .newInstance(params, true, 443);

    try {
        MyThreadSafeClientConnManager.makeScheme(true, false,    
                          ht.mClientCertAlias);

        ccm.registerClientCert(getApplicationContext(), ht);
        // checkCertificate(ht.mClientCertAlias);

    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);

    connectionInfo = this.getConnectionInfo();

    this.url = String.format("%1$s://%2$s/%3$s/%4$s",
            connectionInfo.Protocol, connectionInfo.ServerName,
            connectionInfo.WebserviceName, connectionInfo.Path);

    httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
}


private String callTheWebserviceCertificate() {
    this.setupClient();
    String result = "";

    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = (HttpResponse) this.httpclient.execute(httpGet);
        result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        result = e.getMessage() + "\n";

        for (StackTraceElement el : e.getStackTrace()) {
            result += el.toString() + "\n";
        }

        Log.d(TAG, result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

greetings,
jens

Comment: You might want to show some related code, the above has nothing to do with the actual key or `X509KeyManager`.